# server side search using ajax json jquery

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm retrieving list of users and render these list inside large table. I have custom pagination implemented. Now I want to implement server side search and filtering.

I was thinking to put textbox on top of each column to take user input for example username and to process these data using ajax to mvc controller where I would retrieve data based on that user input and using json show this data on jquery popup window.

Is these solution right approach or you can recommend me some other solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that would be better . You can use Ajax.Action to execute Action in a Controller and instead of using Action Result you can also Json Result return type which can return json results to your view and there you can handle that json result and easily show up in any Jquery Popup window.

Let me Show you how does it work:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Search", "SeachItem", new {item.ItemID}, null) %>
```

This is how you can use **Ajax.ActionLink** where **SearchItem",** is the name of the Controller and pass that Item id that is needed to be searched.

```
     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] // Only allow POSTs (this action causes changes)
     public JavaScriptResult SearchItem(int itemID)
     {
       var itemToDelete = GetItem(itemID);

       // Now tell the browser to update its DOM to match

       JavaScriptEncode(itemToDelete.Name));
       return JavaScript(script);
      }
```

This is in Javascript you can also work same as in Json result and return that json result.

Happy Coding!!!!